# Orthogonal Distance between two contours in Numpy/Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to calculate the orthogonal distance between two contour lines. I have an example of the contours at the following link. https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSfNK.jpg "Contour"

I have tried getting the points associated with the Matplotlib contours using the following code:

```
line = cs.collections[1].get_paths()
p = cs.collections[1].get_paths()[0]
v = p.vertices
x = v[:,0]
y = v[:,1]
```

I use this same approach to get the other points of contours.  My problem is that these points seem to be behind the scenes information that matplotlib uses to plot these contours.  For my purposes the orthogonal distance is the important quantity, and I'm not sure how I would go making that calculation.

Comment: If your vertices are densely spaced (much closer spaced on each contour than the distance between contours) you could just go to each point on contour A and compute the distance to all points on contour B, then take the minimum.  Otherwise, you could fit or interpolate the contours then follow the first prescription.

Comment: If you have an actual function f(x,y) that you are plotting, then the distance between contours is given by the inverse of the amplitude of the gradient and you don't need matplotlib at all.

Comment: @roadrunner66, the points are densely spaced.  unfortunately the points do not come from a function, but matplotlib's contour method. I tried your first suggestion, but that would not necessarily return the orthogonal distance.  I was looking for a more exact solution, but for all intents and purposes that should be fine. i appreciate your answer. thank you.

Comment: The contour method of matplotlib need an input, what array are you using there? Is the array analytical? Does it have any special properties?

Comment: @nicoguaro, the array is a 2d field output from a numerical simulation. the array is dense, and to the best of my knowledge is not analytical.

Comment: By the way, how do you define the orthogonal distance?

Comment: @nicoguaro, the distance by drawing a perpendicular line between the two contours

Comment: Then it should be perpendicular to both of them? What if there are multiple lines that satisfy that condition?

Comment: the contours essentially form a closed loop, so you are correct there will be several.  i need to compute the distances at some specified interval.  the brute force approach i was trying before is quite computationally intensive as these need to be calculated for several hundred timesteps.

Comment: If the spacing of the original points is uniform (numerical solution, cartesian grid) then I would still go for the absolute value of the gradient. You could then interpolate that grid of gradients if you need to know at the exact intersection with your arbitrary contour line vertices.

Comment: @roadrunner66, i'll give it a shot. thanks for the help.

Comment: What about fitting tangent circles between the two contours?

Comment: @nicoguaro i'm just computing the minimum distance between the contours, and that seems to be sufficient for my cases.  thank you guys for all your help.